# how to view Linux files in a window from the windows machine

Tags: windows, linux, putty

I can use putty to access Linux server from a windows machine. But it's kindof inconvenient to navigate through the folders. Is there a way to view the folders in a window (the windows look-and-feel) instead of a terminal?

Thank you for all your help! I'm really a newbie.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest winscp that way you can view the files or copy them over without installing anything unnecessary on the server

Answer (score 0):

Nope, not with putty, it uses a tty response system.  If you or your admin are aiming at using an X window system (basic window manager) try something like an nx server or hamachi/logmein and remote login instead of putty ssh, or just get used to ls's and cd's.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have root on the Linux box, you could set up a network filesystem such as [Samba](http://google.com/search?q=samba) (SMB protocol, as used in normal Windows shares) or NFS (which has a built-in client on Windows, though not installed by default, and I am uncertain of its quality.)

If you just want a file browser built on SSH, I seem to recall the "official" (closed-source) SSH client for Windows from SSH.com does that pretty well.  Haven't used it in years though.

Answer (score 0):

You could run a X Server for Windows on your PC, and then, after connecting with puTTy, set the DISPLAY environment variable to point to your X server display instance.